# Selenium Web driver Handling Non-responsive IE Pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I'm working on an automation project using Selenium Webdriver + Python + Internet Explorer.

Sometimes IE get get hung due to long running scripts and also my automation stops.

[image]

I want to know if there is any way to detect this and resume automation? I mean it will wait for maybe 2 seconds, and if its unable to navigate it will go to next step ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code part where you have done the IE config? The DesiredCapabilities part? Also please try this fix - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175500

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, every test should start it owns browser instance. This means that you can use a command line command to kill previously unclosed IE instances.

```
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe
```

You can kill the processes of the browser using Python of course.

```
import psutil

PROCNAME = "python.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
        proc.kill()
```

I hope that helps you!

Best,

Anton